# How to rename install directory at run-time in Wix

Tags: wix

We have installer generator as part of build process that generate wix files and then build it to create installer. I can customize installation by specifying a wix file and a xpath that tell where to include the file that will customize setup.

It generate install directory structure automatically and i want to use a include file to rename INSTALLDIR name inside by include file. How do i do that. Define a CustomAction? and if yes then how and where should i define it. It should override the default so when installer run and user is given option to choose directory the default path should be the one that i overridden and not the one that is by default generated by our build process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using WixUI_InstallDir (adding `<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>` to your installer code and a reference to WixUIExtension)?  Should be quite simple to add to your installer, alternatively you can edit the existing dialogues you have (if you use them) to add a new control but that's a bit more work.

Check out http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm

Comment: we have that but the default directory i want to add product version since we support multiple version of product in parallel. It would difficult for user to choose different directories every-time and in another case when product is silently install it directory should be unique base of version no. e.g `C:\Programs\CompanyAbC\Product 08.11\ `what we have currently is just  `C:\Programs\CompanyAbC\Product`  so i want to rename `Product` to `Product $(env.MAJ).$(env.MIN)`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a property for your app name and setting up the dir structure like: `<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"> <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder"> <Directory Id="Dir.CompanyName" Name="CompanyAbc"> <Directory Id="Dir.Application" Name="$(var.ApplicationName)"> </Directory></Directory> </Directory> </Directory>`